# Removing a merged pull request from history

Tags: git

A pull request was merged in several days ago and we've decided that the whole thing needs to come out.

A few commits have been put in after this action and I'd like to keep those.

I've included a screenshot of my commit graph below. The commit in question that I'd like to remove is `19fdbd1`.

I attempted to use `git rebase 19fdbd1` to do this but it did not have the intended effect as the feature in question was still present. I most likely did this incorrectly though.

[image: example]

Comment: You mean remove a commit from your commit history right? I am pretty sure you can't make a pull request disappear unless your `git` gui has specific commands / tools for that. (I'm speaking from my experience in GitHub)

Comment: Correct, "remove merged pull request" is what i should have said.

Comment: OK... Well, you can remove commits from your merged pull request by looking at the answer(s) below. From GUI's like Github, you can't make a Pull Request disappear. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18318097/delete-a-closed-pull-request-from-github

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git revert --interactive 19fdbd1`

Now, in the `vim` or your editor terminal that comes up, next to `19fdbd1`, put in :

`squash 19fdbd1 COMMIT MESSAGE`

Now, `git push -f origin BRANCH_NAME`

Boom... `19fdbd1` never existed.

However, if you want the rest of your commit id's to be exactly the same, you can't simply just remove `19fdbd1` directly, and you'll have to do :

git revert `19fdbd1`

This creates a new commit that gets rid of `19fdbd1`

And then simply `git push origin BRANCH_NAME`

Notice there is no `-f` here since we didn't rewrite the commit history, just removed the changes from one particular commit.

Answer (score 1):

Use `git rebase -i` instead to specify exactly how you want to remove the commit. 
(That said, this sounds more like a job for `git revert`.)

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is a very old post, but I have been digging around to see if this is possible in bitbucket - to delete a merged pull request,  and it appears it is not, at least in the server version 7.17.5.  I also tried to see if i could reopen it to then delete it,  and that didnt work either.  There may be a way to do this in the internal database, but that could be playing with fire - obviously not an option for cloud hosted SCMs.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34687316)