# Git filter-branch not filtering pull requests

Tags: git, github, git-filter-branch

I successfully used `git filter-branch` (following the instructions [here](https://help.github.com/articles/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository/)) to remove certain files from my repository. Upon inspection, it looks like they are completely gone from the commit history. However if I open up any of the previously closed pull requests, navigate to the commits and browse the repository at the time of the pull request, it looks like they are still there. Is there any way to rewrite the commit history of all pull requests (or even better: remove closed pull requests altogether)?

Comment: the answer would probably depend on the server used.

Comment: I'm using github.com

Comment: Pull requests are web-server add-ons, not part of Git itself, so it's not surprising that Git itself can't get rid of them either. GitHub in particular have a bunch of extra stuff they do that requires using their interfaces; I don't know if they have a way to clean out old pull requests other than deleting the repository entirely.

Comment: It seems so, after a bit of more searching I stumbled upon this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18318097/delete-a-closed-pull-request-from-github which suggests it's not possible.