# How to remove issue/pull request ids from git commit messages

Tags: git

I'm trying to move the repository from GitHub to TFS. But in the repository of Github the commit messages has reference to GitHub issues and pull requests IDs.

Is there a way to delete the IDs of Github issues and pull requests from the commit messages?

Comment: This is an operation which would rewrite your whole repo history by changing every commit hash, probably using `filter-branch`. Is this just a cosmetic change or do these commit messages actually cause problems in some way?

Comment: The problem is, when I push the repository to the TFS git. The commit messages with ids will get a reference to the User Stories inside of TFS, we don't want that.

I will have a look at `filter-branch`, thanks!

Comment: Please check that [Delete a closed pull request from GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18318097/delete-a-closed-pull-request-from-github?answertab=votes#tab-top)