# Is it possible to delete a pull-request on BitBucket?

Tags: bitbucket

I cannot find an option to delete a PR on BitBucket.
Am I overlooking something or it's really not possible?

Comment: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Delete-a-Pull-Request/qaq-p/74341

Comment: A PR cannot be deleted. Read up here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18318431/4482269

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As per the link [jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe) mentioned, to the right of the merge button there are 3 dots. Under that menu you should have a delete option if you have permission to delete.

This is available only for BitBucket Server, not on BitBucket.org.
In BitBucket.org there is no option to delete the PR.

[image: BitBucketDeletePullRequst]

Comment: But as I understood this feature is not available on BitBucket.org, right?

Comment: @user1941537 I updated the answer. As for now, there is no option to delete the PR from BitBucket.org

Comment: This is NOT available on bitbucket.org.

Answer (score 23):

You can decline a pull request which has the same result -- stopping / removing the PR.

Comment: How is it "the same result"?  What one would want is to have the pull request completely gone without a trace anywhere. That's what "delete" means.

Answer (score 9):

For Bitbucket Cloud, there are no way to do this. One way of getting by is to have a 'dev/junk' branch, used for declined or useless pull requests.
Then just edit the existing request to go into this branch and merge.
Data is still there, in case you need it some day, or if it's sensitive info you can remove the whole branch. If its already declined before, well, nothing can be done then other than recreating that repo

See https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BCLOUD-8089 for the update on this feature request and vote on it!

Answer (score 5):

I wanted to delete a pull request of a branch that had already been merged and deleted. Even though I am an admin of my project, I cannot see any "delete" options. For me what worked was to recreate the deleted branch from the main branch and push it. E.g.

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b [deleted branch name]
git push -u origin [deleted branch name]
```

Then I opened Bitbucket and the branch showed up as "merged" and disappeared from the PRs list.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot delete the PR in bitbucket.org .
Using `Decline` option will do exactly what you want - the PR won't be visible in the tab `Pull requests` (you need to sort PR by `Decline` to see it) but on tab `Branches` you will see that in column `Pull request` you have removed your problematic PR.

PS you cannot undo `Decline` of PR, so take care

Comment: "Using Decline option will do exactly what you want" is pushing it. What one would want is to have the pull request completely gone without a trace anywhere. That's what "delete" means.

Comment: It is not just "pushing it", it is plainly false. When a PR exists, even a declined one, BB will not create another clean one from the same branch. So it's not just a matter of cosmetics or privacy or whatever, the fact that a useless old PR is around has a very tangible effect.

Comment: Would be nice is there was a further "Delete" option to hard delete a "Declined" PR for the case where the PR contains sensitive information that wasn't supposed to go into that environment. It's gone from git, but Bitbucket is persisting it like a bad smell.