# Deleting a Pull Request after Resolving Conflicts on Bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

I resolved a conflict on Bitbucket in a pull request, but now I have two pull requests, and I can't delete them. Is there any other option?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to delete a pull-request on BitBucket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64005844/is-it-possible-to-delete-a-pull-request-on-bitbucket)

Comment: This is related, but in my case this option is deactivated by the admins.

Comment: Looks like that answer covers both bitbucket server and cloud.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pull requests are not a feature of Git itself, but rather of hosting providers such as GitHub, GitLab, and Bitbucket.

If the provider has disabled closing / deleting an unwanted pull request, you'll have to get the provider themselves to do something about it.  Git won't be able to assist here.