# Undo GitHub Merge

Tags: github, merge, pull-request, git-revert

I would like to know the best way to undo a pull request made to the main branch on my GitHub repository.

Context: I don't have a staging server and did everything I could to test some new changes locally, but I missed a few things and want to roll back the merge to add to it before deploying again.

I tried "revert" and I believe this has successfully reverted the changes. I then made a handful of additions and then created a new pull request however GitHub is suggesting the only differences between main and the dev-branch are the latest handful of additions: it does not include all the prior differences between main and the dev-branch.

**EDIT (additional context in response to comment)**: To summarise the overall sequence... I finished work on a branch, created a PR, then merged it to main. When testing on the remote server (production as I don't have another) I realised there was further work required. I wanted to rollback to prior to the merge and used "revert" in GitHub on the web. This does seem to have reverted the changes, but I expected that if I resumed work on the branch (which I hadn't deleted) and then did a subsequent PR when complete, that ALL changes would be included (ie the new changes PLUS the previous differences between the branch and main). This isn't the case... seeimgly only new changes are shown in the diff.

Comment: Are you asking if you can delete a pull request? If so, it's not possible on GitHub. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18318431/10252177).

If you made a mistake in your pull request and are having trouble updating it, the best course of action might be to close it and make a new one.

Comment: I finished work on a branch, created a PR, then merged it to main. When testing on the remote server (production as I don't have another) I realised there was further work required. I wanted to rollback to prior to the merge and used "revert" in GitHub on the web. This does seem to have reverted the changes, but I expected that if I resumed work on the branch (which I hadn't deleted) and then did a subsequent PR when complete, that ALL changes would be included (ie the new changes PLUS the previous differences between the branch and main.)