# How do I delete merged Pull & Request history?

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I would like to delete the record of PR that is in the Close state after the Pull&Request request on GitHub and completed until Merge.

As far as I know, the Github support staff team provides this kind of support. Is that right? I found out by referring to the stackoverflow's writing. ([Delete a closed pull request from GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18318097/delete-a-closed-pull-request-from-github))

https://support.github.com/contact

However, I haven't received a response from "support.github.com/request >> Remove data from a repository Iown or control >> Remove pull requests" 9 hours ago.

The GitHub repository is in a private state Password and access token information were also provided.

Is it right to wait a little longer?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Sorry. Haven't done that before so couldn't really help. Because GitHub is such a big platform, I imagine your request might be in a long queue of help requests that await resolve. You'll probably need to be patient.

Comment: Just curious, why do you need to delete a pull request? Leave it in the system usually doesn't hurt anybody.

Comment: @KoalaYeung Hi, I'm revising the commit date to 1-2 months ago in the process of changing my personal project that I originally worked on with Spring MVC to Springboot RESTful API server project, but I want to get rid of this because the PR request of a completely recent date remains on the record. I wish I could modify the PR date, but I know that there is no such function, so I would rather erase the PR record and proceed with the management only as an issue.